# Why are ring extensions only discussed in the context of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I'm watching the great (imo) set of lectures on abstract algebra from the harvard extension school that's available on youtube.

Now [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArVbqzjQtgU/) lecture is about extending a ring. The lecturer talk about this in the context of extending subrings of $\mathbb{C}$. However, I wonder (as did someone during the lecture but the prof didn't really answer the question) why this is only discussed in the context of subrings of $\mathbb{C}$. But couldn't the same constructions also be made in more general rings? Where a subring of an arbitrary ring is extended by just adjoining some elements from the large ring?

Thanks

Comment: Of course, the notion of ring extension makes sense outside of $\mathbb{C}$. Please consult any book on ring theory. Not just some random lecture.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg A lecture of Benedict Gross is not "just a random lecture", but I agree with you about the advice .

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes I found that out. Thanks for the answer. And yea I'm reading a book aswel as watching those lectures. I think they are very nicely presented and clear lectures by the way, I wouldn't describe them as "just some random lecture", but I guess that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Haha we said that exact same think with regards to those lectures.

Comment: It was not my intention to say that the lecture is not good (I haven't clicked on the link), but rather that it is just **one** lecture.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, just a little bit later he explains that it is indeed not limited to $\mathbb{C}$, I should have been a little bit more patient.

Comment: In number theory one deals with number fields and their rings of integers.  Of course, such rings are subrings of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: By which you mean that they are of particular interest in practice? And so that's a reason they might be introduced first

Comment: Well, of particular interest in number theory, but perhaps not in practice.

Comment: Haha well in my mind number theory is also 'practice' when compared to abstract algebra. Thanks for the replies.